# Returning the path of elements from the specified element to the root in an ArrayList

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Trying to get a path from an element to the root in a binary search tree. 
I feel like im close because it returns the first element but not the entire path.

```
  public java.util.ArrayList<E> getPath(E e) 
{
  TreeNode<E> current = getNode(e);
  java.util.ArrayList<E> path = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

  while(current != null)
  {
      path.add(current.element);
      current = current.parent;

  }
  return path;
}
```

Here is get Node

```
public TreeNode<E> getNode(E element)
{
TreeNode<E> current = root;                   
while (current != null) 
{
    int comp = (element.compareTo(current.element));
  if (comp < 0) 
    {                             
  current = current.left;                         
    } 
    else if (comp > 0) 
    {                      
  current = current.right;                        
    } 
else 
   {           
  return current;                        
   }                                           
  }                                             
    return null;                                  
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty correct to me. What does getNode do and what parameter are you calling getPath with? Also, maybe parent is not set as expected and is always null?

Comment: @Sierra Bravo This is obviously not the standard TreeNode implementation.  Where do .parent and .element come from?

Comment: TreeNode is an inner static class with the following referencesprotected E element;
      protected TreeNode<E> left;
      protected TreeNode<E> right;
      protected TreeNode<E> parent;

Comment: @Sierra Bravo if I had to guess, I'd say `parent` isn't being set correctly